# Como enviar headers em todas as requisições HTTP ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, rest, http-headers

O meu código está assim, gostaria de saber como enviar um token Authorization em todas as requisições http feitas em ionic 3:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-categoria',
  templateUrl: 'categoria.html'
})
export class CategoriaPage {

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  toTest() {

    let data = {};
    let url = 'https://localhost/gestor2.0/public/categoria/';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'TdSa4512csdgfa368747654'
    });

    this.httpClient.post(url, data, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        console.log('sucesso ao salvar');
        console.log(result);
      },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

}
```

**Me retorna este erro ao abrir a página categoria:**

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CategoriaPage -> HttpClient]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CategoriaPage -> HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CategoriaPage -> HttpClient]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CategoriaPage -> HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>       at *NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
>       at NgModuleRef*.get (core.js:12129)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:12619)
>       at c (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Tab.NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
>       at Tab.NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
>       at nav-controller-base.js:263
>       at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
>       at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
>       at polyfills.js:3

Comment: Dá uma olhada: [Implementando Interceptor para requisições HTTP em sua aplicação Angular 4](https://medium.com/@cesarolvr/implementando-interceptor-para-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-http-em-sua-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-angular-4-5dba022dfcb1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Eu costumo a gerar um Service para abstrair os métodos HTTP:

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import {
   Http,
   RequestOptions,
   RequestOptionsArgs,
   Response,
   Request,
   Headers,
   XHRBackend
} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
```

export class HttpServices {

```
headers: HttpHeaders;
options: object;

constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

endpoint: string = environment.apiUrl; //pega o endereço do arquivo environments.ts

get( uri: string ) {
    return this.http.get( this.endpoint + uri ).pipe(
        tap((res: Response) => {
            this.onSuccess(res);
        }),
        retry(0),
        catchError(this.onCatch),
        finalize(() => this.onEnd())
    );
}

post(url: string, data): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post( this.endpoint + url, data )
        .pipe(
            tap((res: Response) => {
                this.onSuccess(res);
            }),
            retry(0), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
            catchError(this.onCatch), // then handle the error
            finalize(() => this.onEnd())
        );
}
```

e nos services específicos como no seu caso - CategoriaService* ficaria assim:

```
// o caminho da abstração das chamadas HTTP
import { HttpServices } from './http.services';

CategoriaService {

  URI = '/categoria'
  // injetando o Service Http criado
  constructor( private httpCustom: HttpServices) {

  }

  salvar( data ) {
    // ja retorna uma Observable
    return this.httpCustom.post( this.URI, data )
  }
}
```

e na hora de usar em uma Page, pode ser usada a Service específica.

Na abstração vc pode implementar os comportamentos padrão, que forem necessários para cada chamada Http.

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraço

Comment: entendi, mas não quero usar Service entende, pq só vou precisar nesta page.

Comment: Entendi. Man, tudo leva a crer que seja alguma coisa no app.module, importar o HttpClientModule  e add no array de imports, como na resposta do @silvio-campos. Pesquisei sobre o erro e a maioria das soluções levam a essa solução.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, me parece que o erro apresentado é por que você não fez a importação do HttpClientModule.

Vá no seu app.module.ts e importa o module.

```js
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: não é não, já fiz o import no appmodule